# What is the meaning of this paragraph of code for calculating auc in ctr prediction？

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, data-mining, auc

Please forgive me for my broken English.
This is the code.

```
def scoreClickAUC(num_clicks, num_impressions, predicted_ctr):  
    """ 
    Calculates the area under the ROC curve (AUC) for click rates 

    Parameters 
    ---------- 
    num_clicks : a list containing the number of clicks 

    num_impressions : a list containing the number of impressions 

    predicted_ctr : a list containing the predicted click-through rates 

    Returns 
    ------- 
    auc : the area under the ROC curve (AUC) for click rates 
    """  
    i_sorted = sorted(range(len(predicted_ctr)),key=lambda i: predicted_ctr[i],  
                      reverse=True)  
    auc_temp = 0.0  
    click_sum = 0.0  
    old_click_sum = 0.0  
    no_click = 0.0  
    no_click_sum = 0.0  

    # treat all instances with the same predicted_ctr as coming from the  
    # same bucket  
    last_ctr = predicted_ctr[i_sorted[0]] + 1.0  

    for i in range(len(predicted_ctr)):  
        if last_ctr != predicted_ctr[i_sorted[i]]:  
            auc_temp += (click_sum+old_click_sum) * no_click / 2.0  
            old_click_sum = click_sum  
            no_click = 0.0  
            last_ctr = predicted_ctr[i_sorted[i]]  
        no_click += num_impressions[i_sorted[i]] - num_clicks[i_sorted[i]]  
        no_click_sum += num_impressions[i_sorted[i]] - num_clicks[i_sorted[i]]  
        click_sum += num_clicks[i_sorted[i]]  
    auc_temp += (click_sum+old_click_sum) * no_click / 2.0  
    auc = auc_temp / (click_sum * no_click_sum)  
    return auc
```

I'm confused with the meaning of paragraph "(click_sum+old_click_sum) * no_click / 2.0  "。please help me。

Comment: It means, take the average of the current value of `click_sum` and its previous value (from the previous `i` loop), and then multiply the average by `no_click`. Does that answer your question? If not, please clarify by updating your question to be more specific :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But why the sum of "(click_sum+old_click_sum) * no_click / 2.0 " over "(click_sum * no_click_sum)" get auc? I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

The area under the curve is *linearly interpolated* when more than one point has the exact same predicted score.

The equation you seeing is the area of a slice which looks like this:

```
   /
  /|
 / |
/  |
|  |
|  |
+--+
```

The are of this can be computed as average height * width = (height_left+height_right)+width/2

Comment: The roc curve's x axis is fp and y axis is tp so that this slice of area's width is the value of false positive rate?

Comment: It's the *change* in fpr, not the total fpr. The area is computed by cutting it into vertical slices at every change.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I see what you mean. tpr = click/(click+no_click) and fpr = no_click/(click+no_click). But why the last computing process is " auc = auc_temp / (click_sum * no_click_sum)  "? Normally the sum of trapezium is auc and we do not need  " auc = auc_temp / (click_sum * no_click_sum)  ".

Comment: That is the scaling to a total area of 1, it's more efficient to do this late.